# TFS - query on all my changes on current sprint

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 12.0.30723.0 and I'm trying to build a query on which I can see the history of all the changes on different tasks for the current sprint for a person. I don't know why the [@CurrentIteration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-by-date-or-current-iteration) is not accepted, so probably I'll change the sprint param in the query when needed. I want to see how many hours have been completed and on which day of the sprint for a person assigned tasks. Basically a history on how many hours and when have been completed.

What I've tried until now, looks like:

[image]

Is this possible to accomplish on TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [MSDN document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-by-date-or-current-iteration#client-restrictions-on-the-use-of-currentiteration-macro), the @CurrentIteration is only could be used in the following clients:

1. Web portal that connects to VSTS
2. Web portal that connects to an on-premises TFS 2015.
3. Visual Studio 2015 connected to TFS 2015 or
   VSTS.

You're using TFS 12.0.30723.0, this is TFS 2013. @CurrentIteration doesn't work for TFS 2013 web port. You could upgrade your TFS to TFS 2015 or higher versions.

About your request, you could add the **AuthorizedDate**, **RemainingWork**, **CompleteWork** field column in the query result. Then you could export your query using Excel to Sum up. Because TFS query doesn't have the calculating feature. The AuthorizedDate shows the time when the workitem is assigned to someone.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my goal is to see how many hours have been completed and on which day of the sprint for a person assigned tasks. Basically a history on how many hours and when have been completed.